# How to show image to another component in vue.js 3 after uploading it from parent component to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs3

After success full upload to firebase:

[image: After success full upload to firebase]

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <GoBack />
    <div class="upload-img">
      <div class="fit-content">
        <p>Upload an Image</p>
        <div class="input-bar">
          <input type="file" @change="previewImage" accept="image/*" />
        </div>
        <div class="progres-bar">
          <p>
            Progress: {{ uploadValue.toFixed() + "%" }}
            <progress id="progress" :value="uploadValue" max="100"></progress>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div v-if="imageData != null">
          <img class="preview" :src="picture" />
          <br />
          <button @click="onUpload">Upload</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <SideBar />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { storage } from "@/includes/firebase";
import GoBack from "./GoBack.vue";
import SideBar from "./SideBar.vue";

export default {
  name: "Upload",
  data() {
    return {
      imageData: null,
      picture: null,
      uploadValue: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    previewImage(event) {
      this.uploadValue = 0;
      this.picture = null;
      this.imageData = event.target.files[0];
    },
    onUpload() {
      this.picture = null;
      const storageRef = storage
        .ref(`${this.imageData.name}`)
        .put(this.imageData);
      storageRef.on(
        `state_changed`,
        (snapshot) => {
          this.uploadValue =
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
        },
        () => {
          this.uploadValue = 100;
          storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            this.picture = url;
          });
        }
      );
    },
  },
  components: { GoBack, SideBar },
};
</script>
```

I want to show my uploaded image to this child component:

[image: I want to show my uploaded image to this child component]

```
<template>
  <GoBack />
  <h1>welcome to friend section</h1>
  <sideBar />
</template>

<script>
import SideBar from "./SideBar.vue";
import GoBack from "./GoBack.vue";

export default {
  props: ["imageView"],
  components: {
    SideBar,
    GoBack,
  },
};
</script>
```

**I want that after image upload to firebase, i want to show that image in child component as shown in 2nd component**

***thankyou***

Comment: Do you have access to `this.imageData.name` in that 2nd component?

Comment: i don't know how to do this, I'm new to vue.js. The 2nd component(child once) I kept it empty so and the code of parent component I provided it. I want to make dynamic image component. I want that user can upload the image and image appears in 2nd component(child once) and remain there until user donnot edit or delete that image